# Dropdown not being filled inside Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select

I have two dropdowns. The first is `RouteTypeSelect` and the second is `RouteNameSelect`.

I want to fill the second on change of the first using Ajax to get the data dynamically from the database. I have tried several ways to fill the dropdown, all are working outside the Ajax post, but when set in the response of the Ajax it is not working:

```
var $select1 = $('#RouteTypeSelect'), $select2 = $('#RouteNameSelect'), $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page1.aspx/GetRouteName",
        data: '{IdRouteType: "3" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data2) {
            options = [];
            $.each($.parseJSON(data2.d), function () {
                var id= this.IdRoute;
                var name= this.Name;
                $("<option></option>", {
                    value: this.IdRoute,
                    text: this.Name
                }).appendTo($('#RouteNameSelect'));
            });
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("Failed!");
        }
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRouteName(string IdRouteType)
{
    List<Route> RouteNameList2 = new List<Route>();
    RouteLogic RouteBLL = new RouteLogic();
    DataTable RouteTypeDT = RouteBLL.SelectRouteByIdRouteType(Convert.ToInt16(IdRouteType));
    for (int i = 0; i < RouteTypeDT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Route g = new Route();
        g.IdRoute = Convert.ToInt32(RouteTypeDT.Rows[i]["IdRoute"]);
        g.Name = RouteTypeDT.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
        RouteNameList2.Add(g);
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RouteNameList2);
}
```

I have tried this@

```
$('#RouteNameSelect3232').append($("<option     />").val(this.IdRoute).text(this.Name));
```

And this:

```
options = [];
options.push('<option value="' + this.IdRoute + '">' + this.Name + '</option>');
```

And this:

```
$select2.html('<option value="' + this.IdRoute + '">' + this.Name + '</option>');
```

Note that `this.Name` and `this.IdRoute` are filled normally

How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE: The below only appends the last value ... I want to append a list of options.

```
$('#RouteNameSelect3232').val(null).trigger('change');
var studentSelect = $('#RouteNameSelect3232');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'AddBus.aspx/GetRouteName',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{IdRouteType: "3" }'
}).then(function (data2) {

    // Create the option and append to Select2
    $.each($.parseJSON(data2.d), function () {
        var option = new Option(this.Name, this.IdRoute, true, true);
        studentSelect.append(option).trigger('change');
    }),

    // Manually trigger the `select2:select` event
    studentSelect.trigger({
        type: 'select2:select',
        params: {
            data: data2
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your "webservice" returns values?

Comment: please share json data for more details feels like you are already getting returning json and performing $.parseJSON() on a json

Comment: try appendTo('#RouteNameSelect') instead of appendTo($('#RouteNameSelect'))

Comment: @reporter yes it is returning values

Comment: @Anadi i did and it did not work

Comment: @PHPWorm... this is my json `[{"IdRoute":3,"Name":"test"}]`

Comment: try without $.parseJSON

Comment: @PHPWorm... i did and if i remove `$.parseJSON` `jquery.min.js` gives me this error `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected`

Comment: are you using select 2 or some other library or simple html select ?

Comment: @PHPWorm... i ama using select2

Comment: That's the problem

Comment: Check it out : https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: @PHPWorm... i tried but the example is for only 1 option... i tried to loop all the options but only the last one is being added

Comment: @PHPWorm... you can find the edit in the question

Comment: Try my solution I have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `select2()` on select after adding new `<option>` in it

Check this Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/963/

Update your success function

```
     success: function (data2) {
                        options = [];
                        $.each($.parseJSON(data2.d), function () {
                            var id= this.IdRoute;
                            var name= this.Name;
$('#RouteNameSelect').append( $("<option>", {
                                value: id,
                                text: name
                            }));
                        });   
        $('#RouteNameSelect').select2()


                    },
```

Comment: it is filled but i am getting a new dropdown under the original dropdown that is empty

Comment: To make it clear it will help you in future you were updating same $("<option> </option>") object again and again

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
$.each([{id:1,value:'hello'},{id:2,value:'hey'}], function () {
    $("<option></option>", {
        value: this.id,
        text: this.value
    }).appendTo($('#myselect'));
});
```

Comment: i have tried this code and its working fine. i think you have issue with your response please check it, it should be valid.